# How do I prove that the intersection of two closed subsets is also closed?

Tags: general-topology

So I am new to topology, and have been working on this proof for a couple of days now. My plan was to somehow show this proof by using the proof for the the intersection of closed sets, but that hasn't worked out for me yet.

Comment: What is your progress?

Comment: What is your definition of closed sets? Is it a set containing all its limit points, or complement of an open set?

Comment: I am currently looking over the definitions of sets and subsets. My definition of a closed set is : A set A is closed if its complement is open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** If $A$ and $B$ are closed sets, use the fact that $(A\cap B)^\complement=A^\complement\cup B^\complement$.

Comment: Union of open sets is open

Comment: It is *because* the complement of the intersection is open that the intersection is closed.

Comment: Oh okay! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

$A,B$ is closed means $A^\complement$ and $B^\complement$ are open, and by the third axiom of a topology $A^\complement \cup B^\complement$ is also open and equals $(A\cap B)^\complement$ (by de Morgan) so that $A \cap B$ is by definition closed (we just saw that its complement is open). Because we have that *arbitrary*  unions of open set are open, in fact *arbitrary* intersections of closed sets are closed, using essentially the same proof.

Comment: So I need to use this definition to show the same proof but for subsets ?

Comment: @DanaShay What do you mean by "the same proof but for subsets?" I use the definition closed iff complement is open. This indeed holds in subspaces too, if that was the question..

Comment: Ô! After rereading it a couple of times, I understand now! Thank you so much!